# R Programming Converting data columns to Rows

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe which had the following structure:

```
Date            Year          quantity
19-JUN-15   2022            958
19-JUN-15   2021            894
18-JUN-15   2020            80
18-JUN-15   2019            96
```

and so on.

I want to transform this to look like this :

```
    Date           2022       2021     2020     2019                     
19-JUN-15          958        894
18-JUN-15                               80       96
```

and so on. Basically I want to make column 1 giving the dates and the rest of the columns are the individual years and the quantity matched according to the coordinates. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df1, Date~Year, value.var='quantity')
```

Or

```
library(tidyr)
spread(df1, Year, quantity)
```

Or

```
 xtabs(quantity~Date+Year, df1)
```